# PHP 5.6 - Memcached - Strict Stadards

Tags: php, memcached

Now that 5.4.x is at EOL, we are making the jump to 5.6 so we can actually get back to working on features. However we are running into the:

```
Strict standards: Declaration of Hobis_Api_Cache::get() should be compatible with Memcached::get($key, $cache_cb = NULL, &$cas_token = NULL, &$udf_flags = NULL)
```

...warning.

It looks like a major SF2 bundle: [LswMemcacheBundle](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle/issues/21) had the same issue, but their "fix" was to switch APIs from Memcached to Memcache, which may work, but we chose Memcached for a reason. However the maintainers of the php wrapper for memcached apparently don't see fixing [this issue](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/126) as high priority. However as more users are compelled to update to 5.5+ due to 5.4 EOL, I think this issue will need to be addressed sooner rather than later.

So my question is, has anyone figured out an elegant solution to this issue?

Our in-house middleware (Hobis_Api) protects us a little bit, in that I can break out the `set` and `get` functions and put them in their own class, which does not extend Memcached, then treat them as wrapper functions based on current php version id, something like this:

```
// Now
class Hobis_Api_Cache extends memcached
{
    public function set($key, $value, $expiry = self::EXPIRY_DEFAULT) {}
}

// Proposed
class Hobis_Api_Cache_Package
{
    public static function set($key, $value, $expiry, $udfs)
    {
        $cache = new Memcached;

        if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50500) {

            $cache->set($key, $value, $expiry);

        } else {

            $cache->set($key, $value, $expiry, $udfs);
        }
    }
}
```

But obviously this will be a PITA b/c I have to update all the calling code from `$cache->set()` to `Hobis_Api_Cache_Package::set()`

Comment: Although I like Pauls answer - another alternative would be to have two files containing Hobis_Api_Cache. One for each version of PHP and include the one which matches the Memcached class you are extending at runtime.

Comment: @SteveE. The problem is, then I would have to maintain multiple files that were 95% similar, and make changes to the autoloader to determine which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx to Paul's suggestion, here's the end result:

```
class Hobis_Api_Cache extends memcached
{
    /**
     * Magic method override so we can use our version of get/set
     *  Otherwise default get/set will break in php 5.5+
     *
     * @param string
     * @param array
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            // Override due to 5.5+ using php-memcache 2.2
            case 'get':

                $this->myGet($arguments);

                break;

            // Override due to 5.5+ using php-memcache 2.2
            case 'set':

                $this->mySet($arguments);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will only work if you extended the memcached class with your own class, if not, then you may want to consider adding your own class.